# How to log processes in daemon-mode?

Tags: process, services, logging

I would like to save the standard output of the program *motion* in a text file. If I don't use motion in daemon-mode I would simply do it by:

```
motion > log.txt
```

But what is the equivalent when I run it in daemon-mode? I cannot specify implicit logging at least according to motion's man page.